# Converting Pandas df to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I'm trying to use statsmodel to build some logit models. I'm running into an error where it's telling me that there is an error converting to float.

```
logit = sm.Logit(logit_df.isFraud, logit_df.columns[1:])

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'high_fraud_cities'
```

If I remove high_fraud_cities, I simply get another error on a different column

I have a dataframe:

- isFraud (binary)
- distance (integer)
- high_fraud_cities (binary)
- is_mobile (binary)

`isFraud   distance   high_fraud_cities   is_mobile
    0          24             1              0
    1          371            1              1
    0          8              0              0`

I tried to find the dtypes:

```
logit_df.dtypes
```

Getting the following results:

- int64
- float64
- int64
- int32

I tried some of the methods recommended on this site including:

**astype**

```
logit = sm.Logit(logit_df.isFraud.astype(float), logit_df.columns[1:].astype(float))
```

**to_numeric**

```
logit_df.isFraud = pd.to_numeric(logit_df.isFraud, errors='coerce')
```

I exported to Excel to check if I have a hidden string or NaN in there but it doesn't show any such issues. Any suggestions for how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data ?

Comment: Yup. Please see the edits above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the training columns as the second parameter to `sm.Logit`, change your code as follows:

```
train_columns = logit_df.columns[1:]
logit = sm.Logit(logit_df.isFraud, logit_df[train_columns])
```